# OOP PHP - Passing methods trough functions

Tags: php

I am new to OOP in PHP and I am trying to understand how it work.
I am trying to implement PDO into a my own class.

This is what I am doing:

```
class db {

    private $options;

    function __construct() {
        $this->options = array(
            'database_host' => DATABASE_HOST,
            'database_name' => DATABASE_NAME,
            'database_user' => DATABASE_USER,
            'database_pass' => DATABASE_PASS
        );

    }

    private function connect() {
        try {
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->options['database_host'] . ';dbname=' . $this->options['database_name'], $this->options['database_user'], $this->options['database_pass']);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $pdo->exec("set names utf8");
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function select($table, $what, $where, $custom) {

        $query = "SELECT " . $what . " FROM " . $table;
        $child = "1";
        $param = array();
        if ($where)
            foreach ($where as $data => $value) {
                if ($child == "1") {
                    $query .= " WHERE " . $data . " = '" . $value . "'";
                    $param[":" . $data] = $value;
                    $child = "next";
                } else {
                    $query .= " AND " . $data . " = '" . $value . "'";
                    $param[":" . $data] = $value;
                }
            }

        if ($custom)
            $query .= ' ' . $custom;

        $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
        if ($statement->execute($param))
            return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return false;
    }

}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to make the function `connect()` communicating with the below one `select()`
When I try to call the `select()` function, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/game/api/class.db.php on line 47
```

I would like that when I call the `select()` function, the `connect()` one connects to the DB and makes all its variables available for the other functions of the class...but I am lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the `$pdo` variable as a property. Currently it is just a variable local to the `connect()` method.

```
class db {
    private $options;
    private $pdo;
}
```

Then use `$this->pdo` to access it from any of the methods. For example in your `connect()`:

```
private function connect() {
    try {
        $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->options['database_host'] . ';dbname=' . $this->options['database_name'], $this->options['database_user'], $this->options['database_pass']);
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->pdo->exec("set names utf8");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Do the same for your other methods, e.g.:

```
$statement = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
```

---

You might prefer to extend the PDO class, rather than having a new class that keeps a property of the PDO object. The difference is when extending it, your `db` class will behave the same as the `PDO` class, except it will have your additional methods available. Whereas with your current code, the `db` class only has methods that you explicitly define.

Comment: when I call the select() one still same error

Comment: You need to use `$this->pdo` throughout the class, not just in the connect method.

Comment: Thanks. I ll accept your answer in 5 mins

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class db {

private $options;
private $oPDO;

function __construct() {
    $this->options = array(
        'database_host' => DATABASE_HOST,
        'database_name' => DATABASE_NAME,
        'database_user' => DATABASE_USER,
        'database_pass' => DATABASE_PASS
    );

    $this->connect();
}

private function connect() {
    try {
        $this->oPDO = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->options['database_host'] . ';dbname=' . $this->options['database_name'], $this->options['database_user'], $this->options['database_pass']);
        $this->oPDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->oPDO->exec("set names utf8");

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function select($table, $what, $where, $custom) {

    $query = "SELECT " . $what . " FROM " . $table;
    $child = "1";
    $param = array();
    if ($where)
    foreach ($where as $data => $value) {
        if ($child == "1") {
            $query .= " WHERE " . $data . " = '" . $value . "'";
            $param[":" . $data] = $value;
            $child = "next";
        } else {
            $query .= " AND " . $data . " = '" . $value . "'";
            $param[":" . $data] = $value;
        }
    }

    if ($custom)
    $query .= ' ' . $custom;

    $statement = $this->oPDO->prepare($query);
    if ($statement->execute($param))
    return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return false;
}
```

}